# Pronunciation of Two-Consonant patchim

Tags: pronunciation

I have just come across the link about pronunciation of two-consonant patchim in Korean. Does anyone know any basics for the rules such as why do the rules exist?
Also is there a simple way to remember it?

I ask for the logic behind the rule because it helps me to remember it easier and faster.

Comment: If I remember correctly, there are voiced and unvoiced consonants. Some consonants are pronounced stronger than others. In such cases the stronger consonant wins. Eg. 짧다, 닭. If there is an ㅇ after the double consonant batchim character, the character with double consonant will get the first consonant and the 2nd consonant goes over to the ㅇ eg 젊은

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) two consonants+consonant o :** 앉아 (sit) => 안자,

젊어 (young) => 절머 (b), 넋이 (spirit)=>넉씨

**2) two consonants+not consonant o :** 넋과 =>넉꽈,

얹다 (put) => 언따, 핥다 (lick) => 할따, 없다 (no existence) => 업따,

넓다 (spacious) => 널따(a), 맑게 (transparent) => 말께 (c)

@ 1) and 2) : **We pronounce first consonant and sencond consonant puts some effect on following letter**

**3) Irregular :** 밟다 (foot)=> 밥따 (compare (a)),

넓죽하다 => 넙쭈카다 (compare (a)), 젊다 => 점따 (compare (b))

맑다 => 막따 (compare (c))